# puppet, what is the difference between '=' and '=>'

Tags: puppet

Seriously, what's the difference between '=' and '=>'?
They both look and feel like variable binding operators.

Also, why does one require a comma after each declaration,
and the other generates a syntax error when it finds a comma?

Comment: PuppetLabs provides a pretty good [Language Reference](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/lang_summary.html) covering these topics, among many others.  You really should read it.

Comment: I tried, but couldn't find anything about the => operator, not even on their operator [ref doc](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_expressions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is used to [assign a value to a variable](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/lang_variables.html#assignment), e.g.

```
$foo = 'bar'
```

There are some advanced ways to assign variables in Puppet 4, but generally speaking whenever it's a $variable on the left hand side of the expression, add no comma and always use `=`.  Further variable assignments are simply separated by new lines.

`=>` is a key-value separator [in hashes](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/lang_data_hash.html#syntax) or lists of attributes in resources:

```
{
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'bar' => 'baz',
}
```

or

```
file { '/etc/foo.conf':
  ensure  => present,
  content => 'bar',
}
```

Note that foo, bar, ensure and content are not variables themselves - they're keys in a hash or attributes.

You'll find a similar design in many languages, e.g. Perl.